# Тестирование сайта на Mac

Tags: тестирование

Подскажите пожалуйста сервис, где можно протестировать сайт на макинтоше.
Нужен не просто скриншот, а именно тест, так как при открытии корзины модального окна, оно появляется и резко скрывается. При встрече заказчик показывал у себя, но сейчас у меня нет ноутбука с mac os.

Comment: Могу предложить виртуалку поставить

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17502280/5951529

Comment: А нельзя ли установить браузер как на маке?

Answer (score 2):

Для тестирования сайтов под различными ОС и браузерами (как ручного, так и автоматизированного) могу посоветовать следующие сервисы:

- [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com/)
- [CrossBrowserTesting](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/)
- [TestingBot](http://testingbot.com/)

Рекомендовать какой-то один не стану, по сути они очень схожи по функционалу, я пробовал работать со всеми тремя, могу только сказать, что первые два несколько удобнее и функциональнее.

Там существует возможность ручного (live) и автоматизированного (с помощью Selenium, например) тестирования под различными ОС и различными браузерами, в том числе и под Mac OS X.

Кроме того, удобно бывает использовать данные сервисы (пробовал с этой целью только первые два) для снятия скриншотов сайта в различных браузерах для последующей визуальной валидации вёрстки.

Хочу заметить, что сервисы эти платные, хотя для профессионального тестировщика или разработчика цены вполне приемлемые, для компании - тем более. К тому же присутствуют определённые бесплатные возможности, которых на первое время вполне хватит.